# If I create my own Linux distro, what is it's source code?

Tags: debian, distributions, source-code, open-source

So I am creating my own live Linux distro based on Debian. If I am right, for it to be truly opensource I need to provide my distro's source code. So where is it? Is it the filesystem (I don't think so) or is it the contents of the live iso? I think that it is the second one but I am not sure. Sorry if this question sounds stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Distribution is a collection of programs with various free and open licenses and various ways of sharing their code, there usually isn't a single place where you can get source code of a distribution. It's neither the filesystem nor the the content of the ISO -- most programs are compiled so the ISO doesn't contain the source code (except tools written in interpreted languages like Python or Bash). If you want to "open everything" you need to:

- Provide source for every program from your distribution. It's 100 % OK (from license pow) to just link to the upstream where people can download the code. Or you can make your source packages (RPM based distributions these would be SRPMs which contain the source archive, patches and RPM spec files) publicly available.
- Provide source for your changes (patches, custom tools and scripts etc.). Link to your public Git repo with these somewhere in the documentation is a good way to publicize this.
- Make your build reproducible by sharing your build tools and methods. This is not required by GPL, but it's a nice touch for a truly open project.

Comment: “there usually isn't a single place where you can get source code of a distribution” — in most cases there is, the distribution repository itself. *E.g.* in RPM-based distros, the source RPMs you mention. “It's 100 % OK (from license pow) to just link to the upstream where people can download the code.” — that depends on the license; in general you’re better off keeping your own copy (upstreams do disappear, even from stable hosting services).

Comment: I'd say source repos have most of the source code, but it's not everything. You wont get build scripts and (in case of Fedora) kickstart files used to create the ISO, but it's not really source code, it's probably just configuration and you won't really get "binary" out of these. Having a "backup" copy of the upstream source is definitely good idea. It would be interesting to see what happens in this case -- you have a GPL program but the source code is lost. Can we still distribute the binary (it's against the GPL, but source is not available any more)?

Comment: Right, the repos don’t (necessarily) have the source code of all the build tools used to construct the distro (Bodhi, Koji, etc.), but they do have the source code for all the packages shipped in the distro, at least. If you distribute a GPL binary without being able to provide the source code, you’re distributing it in violation of the GPL, as I understand it (but I’m not a lawyer), so you’re not allowed to distribute it.

Comment: See section 6d of [the GPL, version 3.0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html): a distributor may use a third party to provide the source code, but the responsibility to make the source code available ultimately rests with the distributor, not the third party.